# Indexing grouped_df object

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to select a column of an object of class `grouped_df` by index gives "Error: index out of bounds". For example

```
x <- mtcars %>% group_by(am, gear) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), disp, hp, drat)
class(x)
#    "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
# For some reason the first column can be selected...
x[1]
#    Source: local data frame [4 x 1]
#    Groups: am
#    am
#     0
#     0
#     1
#     1    
# ...but any index > 1 fails
x[2] 
#   Error: index out of bounds
# Coercing to data frame does the trick...
as.data.frame(x)[2]
#   gear
#      3
#      4
#      4
#      5
#... and so does ungrouping
all(ungroup(x)[2] == as.data.frame(x)[2]) # TRUE
```

This is using R version 3.1.1 and dplyr 0.3.0.2. I'm not sure whether this is a bug or intentional.. Is there any good reason why it works this way? I'd rather not have to remember to ungroup my data frames after using `dplyr` every time...

*Update* Having looked a bit further into this, my guess is that the motivation for defining `[.grouped_df` [this way](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/grouped-df.r#L63) is for the groups to be preserved when calling e.g. `x[1:3]` (which works). However, when the index is not part of the grouping variables, the error above is thrown. Perhaps it could be modified so that in this case it calls `[.tbl_df` and throws a warning at the same time...

*Update 2* `[.grouped_df` has been modified in the development version of dplyr (0.3.0.9000). It still throws an error, but is more clear now, specifying which grouping variables were not included.

```
x[2]
# Error in `[.grouped_df`(x, 2) : 
#     cannot group, grouping variables 'am' not included
```

The best solution I've found so that my code doesn't crash in this situation, is to include `%>% ungroup` at the end of the `dplyr` command chain.

Comment: Using R version 3.1.0 on Windows with dplyr_0.2 I can access all of the columns without problem.

Comment: I'm also getting this error using R 3.1.1 and dplyr 0.3.0.2 on a Mac.

Comment: I get the same error with R 3.1.1 and dplyr 0.3.0.2 on Ubuntu, but I don't think I had this problem when I was using dplyr 0.2. Subsetting using `dplyr`'s `select()` works on non-grouping variables, but I can't subset with brackets or the base `subset()` function. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/170) I guess it is intentional, but wow did it stump me for a while.

Comment: (I actually tried reverting back to dplyr 0.2 and this behavior remains the same on my machine.)

Answer (score 0):

For `group_by`, function`[` can not subset the column of the df except the grouped variables.  See details on [issuse](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/733),