# Find second largest number for a group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know why the codes did not work

```
  dd = function(x){
  t = which.max(x[,'Sepal.Length'])
  data = x[-t,]
  m= max(data[,'Sepal.Length'])
  return(m)
}

iris %>% group_by (Species) %>% do(dd(.))
```

Comment: -1 from me unless you edit and explain what it's supposed to do.  As of right now this falls under the "Why isn't this code working" reason to close.

Comment: Well, it's a bit terse, and could use more explanation (including the error message), but a close threat is a bit harsh. The title is pretty descriptive regarding what's it's supposed to do.

Comment: @eipi10 - have a look at the close description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because after grouping a data frame you cannot always access its columns as you would expect. When the grouping variable is not included in the result it will throw an error. See [Indexing grouped_df object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342991/indexing-grouped-df-object) for a more detailed discussion.

In your case, for example, `iris[, "Sepal.Length"]` works, but if you try this on the grouped data frame it fails.

```
group_by(iris, Species)[, "Sepal.Length"]
# Error: index out of bounds
```

The reason is that the grouping variables are not included in your selected columns. If you try `group_by(iris, Species)[, c("Species", "Sepal.Length")]` you will see it works.

A workaround is to use double bracket or the dollar sign to return a vector rather than a data frame, i.e. `group_by(iris, Species)[["Sepal.Length"]]` or `group_by(iris, Species)$Sepal.Length`.

So, your code will work if you modify it as follows

```
dd = function(x){
  t = which.max(x$Sepal.Length)
  data = x[-t,]
  m= max(data$Sepal.Length)
  return(data.frame(m))
}

iris %>% group_by (Species) %>% do(dd(.))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: Species
#
#     Species   m
#1     setosa 5.7
#2 versicolor 6.9
#3  virginica 7.7
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also use `slice`

```
 library(dplyr)
 iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      distinct(Sepal.Length)%>% 
      arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
      slice(2) %>% 
      select(Sepal.Length)

 #        Species Sepal.Length
 #  1     setosa          5.7
 #  2 versicolor          6.9
 #  3  virginica          7.7
```

Comment: Thx! @akrun But do you know why the `do` function did not work here?

Comment: @MYjx In the new version, what worked previously with `do` is not working. I will check anyway.

Comment: @Henrik No, it won't account for that.  Sorry, I didn't think about that situation.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the info.  I installed the `devel` version so didn't check the CRAN.

Comment: @akrun a nice example with `distinct` and `slice` +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach with `summarise`:

```
myfun <-  function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  sort(u, decreasing = TRUE)[2L]
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(result = myfun(Sepal.Length))

#      Species result
# 1     setosa    5.7
# 2 versicolor    6.9
# 3  virginica    7.7
```

Comment: Thx! but I still try to understand why my codes did no work...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `rank` function, which gives you a number of options for how to deal with repeated values. Here's an example that returns all rows with the second-highest value of `Sepal.Length` in each `Species`.

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(rank(-Sepal.Length, ties.method="min")==2) 

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
2          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
3          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
4          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
5          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
6          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
7          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
```

As to why your code doesn't work: One issue is that it returns a vector, rather than a data.frame. But the code is failing before it even gets to that point. I don't really know what's going wrong, but it has something to with the difference between `x[,"Sepal.Length"]` and `x$Sepal.Length`. Hopefully someone else can jump in and explain exactly what the issue is. Here's an updated version of your code that works:

```
dd = function(x){
  t = which.max(x$Sepal.Length)
  x = x[-t,]
  m = max(x$Sepal.Length)
  return(as.data.frame(m))
}

iris %>% group_by (Species) %>% do(dd(.))

     Species   m
1     setosa 5.7
2 versicolor 6.9
3  virginica 7.7
```

Changing from `x[,"Sepal.Length"]` to`x$Sepal.Length` takes care of the error you were getting. But you'll get a new error if you don't also return `m` as a data.frame, rather than a vector.

Comment: hi @eipi10 thx for your response! I am curious about the `x[,"Sepal.Length"]` as well..

Comment: See @konvas answer, he explains it.