# In R, how do you select for a data frame that has been grouped?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called, alldataless, generated from a script.

```
> dim(alldataless)
[1] 180  68

> str(alldataless)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 180 obs. of  68 variables:
$ subject                   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ activityLabel             : Factor w/ 6 levels "LAYING","SITTING",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I want to be able to run the below command, but I get an error:

> alldataless[,2]

```
Error: index out of bounds
```

I believe this has something to do with the grouping used in the data frame, but I still can't figure out what command I need to run.

Also, more explicit selections don't help either. Here it returns information about every single column in the data frame:

```
> alldataless[alldataless$activityLabel]
Source: local data frame [180 x 180]
Groups: subject

   subject      activityLabel tBody_Acc_Mean_X tBody_Acc_Mean_Y tBody_Acc_Mean_Z
1        1             LAYING        0.2215982     -0.040513953       -0.1132036
2        1            SITTING        0.2612376     -0.001308288       -0.1045442
3        1           STANDING        0.2789176     -0.016137590       -0.1106018
4        1            WALKING        0.2773308     -0.017383819       -0.1111481
5        1 WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS        0.2891883     -0.009918505       -0.1075662
6        1   WALKING_UPSTAIRS        0.2554617     -0.023953149       -0.0973020
7        2             LAYING        0.2813734     -0.018158740       -0.1072456
8        2            SITTING        0.2770874     -0.015687994       -0.1092183
9        2           STANDING        0.2779115     -0.018420827       -0.1059085
10       2            WALKING        0.2764266     -0.018594920       -0.1055004
..     ...                ...              ...              ...              ...
Variables not shown: tBody_Acc_Std_X (dbl), subject (int), activityLabel (fctr),
```

My ultimate objective is to be able to remove this column and other columns without error:

> alldataless[, -c(alldataless$activityLabel)]

```
Error: index out of bounds
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342991/indexing-grouped-df-object has an identical question but it was not answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert it to a `data.frame` first, then it will work:

```
as.data.frame(alldataless)[,2]
```

Or as has been suggested:

```
as.data.frame(alldataless)[,'activityLabel']
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an object created by functions in the 'dplyr' package. For instance, the question in [Indexing grouped_df object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342991/indexing-grouped-df-object) had a report of a similar error but others (including me) were unable to reproduce. The answer from, @CephBirk didn't make a lot of sense since the material you posted indicated that it already had a 'data.frame' class. I think this is likely a bug restricted to one or more of the platforms or versions of dplyr and R. You need to post a reproducible example such as the one cited. It didn't seem to exist in version 0.2.0, but perhaps a later versions of dplyr introduced a bug. Try the example cited:

```
# With version 2.0
x <- mtcars %>% group_by(am, gear) %>% 
               summarise_each(funs(sum), disp, hp, drat)
class(x)

> x[,2]
[1] 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with your example.

> x <- mtcars %>% group_by(am, gear) %>% 
+     summarise_each(funs(sum), disp, hp, drat)
> class(x)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> x[,2]
Error: index out of bounds

Comment: @user1744318 It works for me.  I use `R 3.1.2` and `dplyr_0.3`

Comment: RStudio 0.98.1087, R 3.1.2, dplyr 0.3.0.2

Comment: I'm having the same problem with dplyr 0.4.3

Comment: I'm having no problems with dplyr v 0.4.3.9001 using the example I offered. If your example is different, then please post another question. When doing so instead of posting the print output as seen from user1744318, please use `dput` to post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This happen when i use tidyverse package, try

```
ungroup(alldataless)
```

works for me.